# getting json_encode to not escape html entities

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, json

I send `json_encoded` data from my PHP server to iPhone app. Strings containing html entities, like `'&'` are escaped by `json_encode` and sent as `&amp;`.

I am looking to do one of two things:

- make `json_encode` not escape html entities. Doc says 'normal' mode shouldn't escape it but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas?
- make the iPhone app un-escape html entities cheaply. The only way I can think of doing it now involves spinning up a `XML/HTML parser` which is very expensive. Any cheaper suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither PHP 5.3 nor PHP 5.2 touch the HTML entities.

You can [test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7l1tT5) this with the following code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain"); //makes sure entities are not interpreted
$s = 'A string with &amp; &#x6F8 entities';
echo json_encode($s);
```

You'll see the only thing PHP does is to add double quotes around the string.

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode` does not do that. You have another component that is doing the HTML encoding.

If you use the `JSON_HEX_` options you can avoid that any `<` or `&` characters appear in the output (they'd get converted to `\u003C` or similar JS string literal escapes), thus possibly avoiding the problem:

```
json_encode($s, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT)
```

though this would depend on knowing exactly which characters are being HTML-encoded further downstream. Maybe non-ASCII characters too?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [manual](http://php.net/json_encode) it appears that json_encode shouldn't be escaping your entities, unless you explicitly tell it to, in PHP 5.3. Are you perhaps running an older version of PHP?

Comment: Yea, I'm using 5.2.6
So pre-5.3 json_encode didn't escape html entities by default?

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Artefacto's answer, I would recommend using this header, it's specifically designed for JSON data instead of just using plain text.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //Also makes sure entities are not interpreted
$s = 'A string with &amp; &#x6F8 entities';
echo json_encode($s);
```

Make sure you check out this post for more specific reasons why to use this content type, [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/2934528)